# ANSI C : How do I abstract over over struct fields?

Tags: c, c89

I have an image represented as 2D array of RGB pixels.

```
typedef struct {
    char R;
    char G;
    char B;
} RGB;
```

and a function that calculates new color for each pixel to that image :

```
RGB new_color(RGB image[][], int r, int c){
    RGB color;
    color.R = image[r][c].R + image[r+1][c].R + image[r-1][c].R + image[r][c+1].R + image[r][c-1].R;
    color.G = image[r][c].G + image[r+1][c].G + image[r-1][c].G + image[r][c+1].G + image[r][c-1].G;
    color.B = image[r][c].B + image[r+1][c].B + image[r-1][c].B + image[r][c+1].B + image[r][c-1].B;
    return color;
}
```

Is it possible to remove the code duplication in new_color body? In other words abstract over the field names of RGB data structure?

Comment: Your choices are basically either macro grossness, or changing your struct content to e.g. `char [3]`.

Comment: While macros are generally frowned upon, they do have their place in C. And on this occasion using a (suitable named, commented and documented) macro could be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's ignore for now that `RGB image[][]` is not legal in C89.

You can factor out accessor functions.

```
char *get_RGB_R(RGB* rgb) { return &rgb->R; }
char *get_RGB_G(RGB* rgb) { return &rgb->G; }
char *get_RGB_B(RGB* rgb) { return &rgb->B; }
```

And then write a helper function that uses them.

```
void set_color_channel_from_adjacent(
    char *(*accessor)(RGB*), RGB* result, RGB image[][], int r, int c)
{
    *accessor(result) = *accessor(&image[r][c]) +
                        *accessor(&image[r+1][c]) + 
                        *accessor(&image[r-1][c]) + 
                        *accessor(&image[r][c+1]) + 
                        *accessor(&image[r][c-1]);
}
```

And then call the helper function

```
RGB new_color(RGB image[][], int r, int c)
{
    RGB color;
    set_color_channel_from_adjacent(get_RGB_R, &color, image, r, c);
    set_color_channel_from_adjacent(get_RGB_G, &color, image, r, c);
    set_color_channel_from_adjacent(get_RGB_B, &color, image, r, c);
    return color;
}
```

Modern compilers will inline the short functions and generate code eqivalent to the original.